# Texture deforming, 4 points

Tags: java, image-processing

i am writing simple 3d game in Java and i need code / lib for texture deforming. I don't want to use OpenGL.

**Example:**

I have got texture:

[image: Texture]

And i need deform it to:

[image: Deformed]

I hope everybody can understand me. Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? What is the input and output of the method you want to write? How do you want to specify the transformation? You need a 3x3 matrix at least (because a 2x2 matrix only works for affine transforms, and yours looks like perspective to me)...

Comment: I need to deform BufferedImage, or array of pixels (int[] rgbs)

Comment: And do you have any way of specifying how it should be transformed? You *do* have to think of those details.

Comment: My guess - based on the title - would be that he just wants to specify the 4 new corner positions. However, this is not sufficient, because it can hardly capture the distortion (the "cells" being narrower when they are "far away"). Anything that you could do here solely based on a `BufferedImage` would look rather messy and could be considered as a "hack" anyhow. This is clearly a task for a 3D API.

Comment: I don't know. I have tried something, but my brain isn't good for that. I have got only 4 points (4x + 4y) and BufferedImage. I am asking, how can i do that.

Comment: Posted a hacky answer down below. If it makes your head ache, I recommend using LibGDX for your java-based game-programming needs. Doing 3D from scratch requires lots of math.

Comment: @YepPossible Nope, not possible ( :-D ). You simply can't extract the distortion from these 4 points. You could only try to "guess" the transformation, when you are *assuming* that this is in fact a *perspective* transformation. But when only the 4 points are given, this information is simply not sufficient.

Comment: Everything is possible! I think i must use my brain for 1000%.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

OK, here we go. Implemented as a small, self-contained example where you can drag around the corners with the mouse:

[image: Pseudo3D]

+1 to...

- tucuxi who already posted the basic approach in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24341270/3182664)
- MvG at math.stackexchange.com who described [how to compute a projective transformation from 4 points](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/339033/133498)

Here's the code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Pseudo3DTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        BufferedImage image = null;
        try
        {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("lena512color.png"));
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        f.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
        f.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image)));
        f.getContentPane().add(new Pseudo3DImagePanel(image));
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class Pseudo3DImagePanel extends JPanel
    implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener
{
    private final BufferedImage inputImage;
    private final Point2D p0;
    private final Point2D p1;
    private final Point2D p2;
    private final Point2D p3;
    private Point2D draggedPoint;

    Pseudo3DImagePanel(BufferedImage inputImage)
    {
        this.inputImage = inputImage;
        this.p0 = new Point2D.Double(30,20);
        this.p1 = new Point2D.Double(50,400);
        this.p2 = new Point2D.Double(450,300);
        this.p3 = new Point2D.Double(430,100);
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        BufferedImage image = Pseudo3D.computeImage(inputImage, p0, p1, p2, p3);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);

        int r = 8;
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval((int)p0.getX()-r, (int)p0.getY()-r, r+r, r+r);
        g.fillOval((int)p1.getX()-r, (int)p1.getY()-r, r+r, r+r);
        g.fillOval((int)p2.getX()-r, (int)p2.getY()-r, r+r, r+r);
        g.fillOval((int)p3.getX()-r, (int)p3.getY()-r, r+r, r+r);
    }



    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        Point p = e.getPoint();
        int r = 8;
        if (p.distance(p0) < r) draggedPoint = p0;
        if (p.distance(p1) < r) draggedPoint = p1;
        if (p.distance(p2) < r) draggedPoint = p2;
        if (p.distance(p3) < r) draggedPoint = p3;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if (draggedPoint != null)
        {
            draggedPoint.setLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
            repaint();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
        draggedPoint = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {}
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
}



class Pseudo3D
{
    static BufferedImage computeImage(
        BufferedImage image,
        Point2D p0, Point2D p1, Point2D p2, Point2D p3)
    {
        int w = image.getWidth();
        int h = image.getHeight();

        BufferedImage result =
            new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        Point2D ip0 = new Point2D.Double(0,0);
        Point2D ip1 = new Point2D.Double(0,h);
        Point2D ip2 = new Point2D.Double(w,h);
        Point2D ip3 = new Point2D.Double(w,0);

        Matrix3D m = computeProjectionMatrix(
            new Point2D[] {  p0,  p1,  p2,  p3 },
            new Point2D[] { ip0, ip1, ip2, ip3 });
        Matrix3D mInv = new Matrix3D(m);
        mInv.invert();

        for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
            {
                Point2D p = new Point2D.Double(x,y);
                mInv.transform(p);
                int ix = (int)p.getX();
                int iy = (int)p.getY();
                if (ix >= 0 && ix < w && iy >= 0 && iy < h)
                {
                    int rgb = image.getRGB(ix, iy);
                    result.setRGB(x, y, rgb);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    // From https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296794
    private static Matrix3D computeProjectionMatrix(Point2D p0[], Point2D p1[])
    {
        Matrix3D m0 = computeProjectionMatrix(p0);
        Matrix3D m1 = computeProjectionMatrix(p1);
        m1.invert();
        m0.mul(m1);
        return m0;
    }

    // From https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296794
    private static Matrix3D computeProjectionMatrix(Point2D p[])
    {
        Matrix3D m = new Matrix3D(
            p[0].getX(), p[1].getX(), p[2].getX(),
            p[0].getY(), p[1].getY(), p[2].getY(),
            1, 1, 1);
        Point3D p3 = new Point3D(p[3].getX(), p[3].getY(), 1);
        Matrix3D mInv = new Matrix3D(m);
        mInv.invert();
        mInv.transform(p3);
        m.m00 *= p3.x;
        m.m01 *= p3.y;
        m.m02 *= p3.z;
        m.m10 *= p3.x;
        m.m11 *= p3.y;
        m.m12 *= p3.z;
        m.m20 *= p3.x;
        m.m21 *= p3.y;
        m.m22 *= p3.z;
        return m;
    }

    private static class Point3D
    {
        double x;
        double y;
        double z;

        Point3D(double x, double y, double z)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.z = z;
        }
    }

    private static class Matrix3D
    {
        double m00;
        double m01;
        double m02;
        double m10;
        double m11;
        double m12;
        double m20;
        double m21;
        double m22;

        Matrix3D(
            double m00, double m01, double m02,
            double m10, double m11, double m12,
            double m20, double m21, double m22)
        {
            this.m00 = m00;
            this.m01 = m01;
            this.m02 = m02;
            this.m10 = m10;
            this.m11 = m11;
            this.m12 = m12;
            this.m20 = m20;
            this.m21 = m21;
            this.m22 = m22;
        }

        Matrix3D(Matrix3D m)
        {
            this.m00 = m.m00;
            this.m01 = m.m01;
            this.m02 = m.m02;
            this.m10 = m.m10;
            this.m11 = m.m11;
            this.m12 = m.m12;
            this.m20 = m.m20;
            this.m21 = m.m21;
            this.m22 = m.m22;
        }

        // From http://www.dr-lex.be/random/matrix_inv.html
        void invert()
        {
            double invDet = 1.0 / determinant();
            double nm00 = m22 * m11 - m21 * m12;
            double nm01 = -(m22 * m01 - m21 * m02);
            double nm02 = m12 * m01 - m11 * m02;
            double nm10 = -(m22 * m10 - m20 * m12);
            double nm11 = m22 * m00 - m20 * m02;
            double nm12 = -(m12 * m00 - m10 * m02);
            double nm20 = m21 * m10 - m20 * m11;
            double nm21 = -(m21 * m00 - m20 * m01);
            double nm22 = m11 * m00 - m10 * m01;
            m00 = nm00 * invDet;
            m01 = nm01 * invDet;
            m02 = nm02 * invDet;
            m10 = nm10 * invDet;
            m11 = nm11 * invDet;
            m12 = nm12 * invDet;
            m20 = nm20 * invDet;
            m21 = nm21 * invDet;
            m22 = nm22 * invDet;
        }

        // From http://www.dr-lex.be/random/matrix_inv.html
        double determinant()
        {
            return
                m00 * (m11 * m22 - m12 * m21) +
                m01 * (m12 * m20 - m10 * m22) +
                m02 * (m10 * m21 - m11 * m20);
        }

        final void mul(double factor)
        {
            m00 *= factor;
            m01 *= factor;
            m02 *= factor;

            m10 *= factor;
            m11 *= factor;
            m12 *= factor;

            m20 *= factor;
            m21 *= factor;
            m22 *= factor;
        }

        void transform(Point3D p)
        {
            double x = m00 * p.x + m01 * p.y + m02 * p.z;
            double y = m10 * p.x + m11 * p.y + m12 * p.z;
            double z = m20 * p.x + m21 * p.y + m22 * p.z;
            p.x = x;
            p.y = y;
            p.z = z;
        }

        void transform(Point2D pp)
        {
            Point3D p = new Point3D(pp.getX(), pp.getY(), 1.0);
            transform(p);
            pp.setLocation(p.x / p.z, p.y / p.z);
        }

        void mul(Matrix3D m)
        {
            double nm00 = m00 * m.m00 + m01 * m.m10 + m02 * m.m20;
            double nm01 = m00 * m.m01 + m01 * m.m11 + m02 * m.m21;
            double nm02 = m00 * m.m02 + m01 * m.m12 + m02 * m.m22;

            double nm10 = m10 * m.m00 + m11 * m.m10 + m12 * m.m20;
            double nm11 = m10 * m.m01 + m11 * m.m11 + m12 * m.m21;
            double nm12 = m10 * m.m02 + m11 * m.m12 + m12 * m.m22;

            double nm20 = m20 * m.m00 + m21 * m.m10 + m22 * m.m20;
            double nm21 = m20 * m.m01 + m21 * m.m11 + m22 * m.m21;
            double nm22 = m20 * m.m02 + m21 * m.m12 + m22 * m.m22;

            m00 = nm00;
            m01 = nm01;
            m02 = nm02;
            m10 = nm10;
            m11 = nm11;
            m12 = nm12;
            m20 = nm20;
            m21 = nm21;
            m22 = nm22;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Impressive answer - all that is left is some kind of anti-aliasing :-)

Comment: Very usefull answer, precise.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know of any standard Java implementation, but the following code (using LibGDX to provide points and matrix operations) works for me. To get the transformation matrix I use `getProjectionMatrix`; once I have it, I can transform points using something similar to `transformPoints` above. You could call `transformPoints` for each of the "square pixels" in your first image, and would get the corners for the corresponding "projected pixel" in the second image. This is slow, but hey, nobody is forcing you *not* to use OpenGL...

```
/**
 * Transforms all points in a polygon using a 3x3 projection matrix.
 * 
 * @param t
 *            the 3x3 transform matrix
 * @param points
 *            the points to transform. Coordinates will be overwritten
 */
public static void transformPoints(Matrix3 t, Vector2... points) {
    Vector3 v3 = new Vector3();
    for (Vector2 v : points) {
        v3.set(v.x, v.y, 1);
        v3.mul(t);
        v.set(v3.x / v3.z, v3.y / v3.z);
    }
}

private static Matrix3 mapBasisToImage(Vector2[] v) {
    // solve (v1 v2 v3) * <a b c> = v4 using <a b c> = (v1 v2 v3)^-1 * v4
    Matrix3 v123 = new Matrix3(new float[] { v[0].x, v[0].y, 1, v[1].x,
            v[1].y, 1, v[2].x, v[2].y, 1 });
    Vector3 v4 = new Vector3(new float[] { v[3].x, v[3].y, 1 });
    float[] M = v123.val.clone();
    v4.mul(v123.inv());
    // scale by solutions
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        M[i + 0] *= v4.x;
        M[i + 3] *= v4.y;
        M[i + 6] *= v4.z;
    }
    Matrix3 bti = new Matrix3(M);
    return bti;
}

/**
 * Calculates a projection matrix from two corresponding sets of four
 * non-collinear 2d vertices. Notice that "view" and "world" are actually
 * interchangeable. Use sparingly: several intermediate matrices are
 * required, and performance may suffer if called in a tight loop.
 * 
 * @param view
 *            four points in the "view" (a camera pointed at the world,
 *            probably with some kind of perspective distortion)
 * @param world
 *            four corresponding points in the "world" (where distances and
 *            angles are correct)
 * @return a 3d projection that can be used to transform any view-based 2d
 *         vector into 'real space', and inverted to undo the process.
 * @see <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/dFrHS/1/">this example</a>, referenced
 *      and described an excellent @see <a
 *      href="http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296794/">
 *      math.stackexchange.com answer</a>.
 */
public static Matrix3 getProjectionMatrix(Vector2[] view, Vector2[] world) {

    Matrix3 A = mapBasisToImage(view);
    Matrix3 B = mapBasisToImage(world);

    // combined - translates any vector from v-space to w-space
    return B.mul(A.inv());
}
```

Converting it to standard Java classes should be easy (although standard Java has no Point3D, you just need x, y and z; and there are plenty of simple matrix inversion & multiplication libraries out there).