# Draw image as trapezoid in java

Tags: java, graphics2d, graphic

I have a requirement to draw a png/jpg in a trapezium shape.
.For ex : height reducing gradually along the x-axis. I could not find an API to do such, I see there is an API AffineTransform which may do such sorts, but could not figure out if trapezium could be achieved. Thanks for your help in advance

I tried something of this sorts,

```
            Image image = imageIcon.getImage();
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            AffineTransform saveXform = g2.getTransform();
            AffineTransform toCenterAt = new AffineTransform();
            //toCenterAt.concatenate(toCenterAt);
            toCenterAt.translate(-(image.getWidth(null)/2), -(image.getHeight(null)/2));
            //toCenterAt.setToRotation(5,4,4,4);
            toCenterAt.scale(0.1, 1);


            g2.transform(toCenterAt);

            g2.drawImage(image, 200,200, null);

            g2.setTransform(saveXform);
```

Comment: What did you tried so far? Please edit your question!

Comment: You might consider having a look at `AffineTransform`s `shear` methods

Comment: (also @MadProgrammer) In an [Affine Transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) parallel lines remain parallel. So there is no way to create a (non-trivial) trapezoidal shape from a rectangle with an affine transform. There are solutions, e.g. like this [general image distortion based on 4 corner points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24341033/texture-deforming-4-points/24344967#24344967) that I created a while ago, but note that this was just a small proof of concept. For good performance, some game engine (with underlying OpenGL) may be more appropriate.