# Auto transforming BufferedImage from side view/not perpendicular to perpendicular based on 4 points printed on list in Java

Tags: java, opencv, matrix-transform

**I see a lot of people just reading it... Maybe you need some extra info? Comment below and I'll give it!**

As my previous questions were saying, I'm building a car that will orientate in the room based on an image that you would have taken with your phone. For that i would need an image that would represent the room. Since you cant take picture directly from the top of the room (unless you are a bird), I would need to transform it to a "perpendicular" image. It would be weird if you would have to do it manually so I decided to do it automatically. Now that is something harder :) Well I asked for transforming image in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34954955/java-transforming-bufferedimage-subimage-defined-by-4-points#comment57647525_34954955) thread and got that marked comment that solved part of my program. I'm still looking for a way to automate that. Since i need the image to be the same size as it would be in real life (we can take 1 pixel as 1 cm), we will probably need some kind of "points of reference" printed on an A4 paper sheet. Also, there will probably be needed some OpenCV since we will need to know the distance between two points in image. Besides that, how would you define the "correction" that has to be done based on four points?

I've done some pics for visual reference:

Id like to transform image like this:
[image: Non aligned image]

To image like this (or even better):
[image]

**EDIT:** I'd like to do this in latest (3.1) version of which i have no idea about how to use it :)

**EDIT #2:** I've done some work on it, solving part of it in this post: [Image perspective correction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609627/image-perspective-correction)

Comment: You could only guess the perspective. From a single image, this is hard or nearly impossible (unless you can identify an object of which you *know* that is rectangular, and derive the perspective from that). For multiple images (video, webcam...) you could have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform and related (computer-vision) tracking mechanism. An active field of research. (Very active, due to the recent hype of self-driving cars - obviously, to some extent, related to your task....)